# Testing soap with Multimechanize

Tags: python, testing, soap, automation, mechanize

I'm trying to test a simple webservice using multimechanize, but I'm having some issues... I tried the same urls and also the same xml in jmeter and I got the right results

http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx
http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather

Here is my python code

import urllib2
import time

class Transaction(object):
    def **init**(self):
        self.custom_timers = {}
        with open('/Users/moisessiles/multimech/gapProject/test_scripts/soap.xml') as f:
            self.soap_body = f.read()

```
def run(self):
    req = urllib2.Request(url='http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx', data=self.soap_body)
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml')
    req.add_header('SOAPAction', 'http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetWeather')

    start_timer = time.time()
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    content = resp.read()
    latency = time.time() - start_timer

    self.custom_timers['Example_SOAP_Msg'] = latency

    assert (resp.code == 200), 'Bad HTTP Response'
    #assert ('Data Not Found' in content), 'Failed Content Verification'
```

Here is the xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <GetWeather xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
          <CityName>San Jose</CityName>
          <CountryName>Costa Rica</CountryName>
        </GetWeather>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

and this is the ouput

1, 0.259, 1396560721, user_group-1, 0.253, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
2, 0.489, 1396560721, user_group-1, 0.229, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
3, 0.721, 1396560721, user_group-1, 0.232, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
4, 0.949, 1396560722, user_group-1, 0.228, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
5, 1.190, 1396560722, user_group-1, 0.241, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
6, 1.422, 1396560722, user_group-1, 0.231, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
7, 1.653, 1396560722, user_group-1, 0.231, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
8, 1.885, 1396560723, user_group-1, 0.231, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
9, 2.123, 1396560723, user_group-1, 0.238, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
10, 2.373, 1396560723, user_group-1, 0.249, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
11, 2.615, 1396560723, user_group-1, 0.242, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
12, 2.849, 1396560724, user_group-1, 0.234, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
13, 3.108, 1396560724, user_group-1, 0.258, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
14, 3.359, 1396560724, user_group-1, 0.251, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}
15, 6.581, 1396560727, user_group-1, 3.222, HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, {}

analyzing results...

transactions: 15
errors: 15

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your problem using Fiddler.
Pretty much you are getting a 415 status code from the server :

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 06 Apr 2014 14:57:02 GMT
Content-Length: 76

The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.
```

The problem here is that you are sending a SOAP 1.1 payload which does not support the Content type application/soap+xml .

If you want to address the issue, you can either use a SOAP 1.2 payload :

```
POST http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.webservicex.net
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 420
SOAPAction: "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetWeather"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetWeather xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <CityName>San Jose</CityName>
      <CountryName>Costa Rica</CountryName>
    </GetWeather>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

This request will work like a charm . However, the Web Service does not return data for San Jose :) maybe for Liberia?

However, if you still want to send a SOAP 1.1 envelope, then just change the Content-type header : This should work :

```
POST http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 411
SOAPAction: "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetWeather"
Host: www.webservicex.net

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetWeather xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <CityName>Liberia</CityName>
      <CountryName>Costa Rica</CountryName>
    </GetWeather>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```